# how can I target one particular div to animate thats using the same class name

Tags: jquery

how can I target the div class (`.desc_wrap`) I have clicked with the mouse to animate rather then the all the divs using the same class name?

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('.desc_wrap').show();
    $('a#toggle').click(function() {
        $('.desc_wrap').slideToggle(700);
        return false;
    });
});
```

**HTML EDIT II**

```
<div class="entry">

<div id="button_wrap">

</div>


<div class="desc_wrap">

</div>


<div id="project_tech">

</div>

<!--- ENDS THE DESC WRAP--->
</div>


<div id="project_images">


</div>

<!--ENDS THE ENTRY WRAP-->
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the html part of the code?

Comment: Show us your HTML, it would help with this.

Comment: Is the target a unique decendant of the `<a>`?

Comment: The `a#toggle` selector seems incorrect.  If it's an ID it's unique and the `a` prefix isn't needed. If there is more than one `toggle` ID then you should be using a class not an ID

Comment: In the future, if you are debugging client-side code (JavaScript) then post the client-side code... this is PHP, you should visit this page in a browser, view the source, and post that code so we know what the end result looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like in your HTML that you can select the `.desc_wrap` element by getting the parent of the `#toggle` element, then getting the siblings of that element, one of which will be the `.desc_wrap` element:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('.desc_wrap').show();
    $('a#toggle').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().nextAll('.desc_wrap').first().slideToggle(700);
        return false;
    });
});
```

If you want to re-use this code then you will probably need to change `id="toggle"` to `class="toggle"` and then select all the toggle links like this: `$('.toggle').click...`

Here is a demo: http://jsbin.com/erimey/edit#javascript,html,live

Answer (score 0):

You can identify it by its parent element and then apply the function to the child of that parent that haves the class.

```
$('selector').children('child-element')
```

Comment: why the down-vote? It's not a perfect answer but given the information posted in the question, this actually has a chance at working (allowing the element to actually be toggled rather than just hidden).

Comment: There seems to be a rash of down voting even when the answer is a viable option.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `.desc_wrap` is a parent element of the element you clicked on (`$(this)`), the [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method should work:

```
$( function() { 
  $( '.desc_wrap' ).show();

  $( 'a#toggle' ).click( function( evt ) {
    $(this).closest( '.desc_wrap' ).slideToggle( 700 );

    evt.preventDefault();
  } );
} );
```

*(Aside: `preventDefault()` is a better way to, well, prevent the default behavior of a clicked link than `return false;`.)*

If `.desc_wrap` is actually a descendent of the element clicked on, just use `this` as your context in the selector:

```
$( '.desc_wrap', this ).slideToggle( 700 );
```

Comment: Wouldn't that negate the `slideToggle` though? Once you `slideUp` the element you won't be able to click the link again.

Comment: Why is `preventDefault()` better than `return false;`?

Comment: that doesn't seem to do anything to the desc_wrap :S I've added the HTML in now if you want to take a look

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('.desc_wrap').click(function() {
       // $(this) represents the div.desc_wrap element you clicked on
       $(this).slideToggle(700);
    });
});
```

Comment: I answered the same, but it doesn't make sense because when the element is slid out of view it's given the CSS `display : none`, so you can't click on it again...

Comment: Maybe he chosed slideToggle on purpose.

Comment: That's actually what I meant, if the OP is using `slideToggle` then I'd assume they want to be able to show/hide the element, rather than just going one way.